# Swift - How to draw line in OpenGL ES?

Tags: ios, swift, opengl-es

I'm trying to draw a black single line on `GLKitView`, using `Swift`, but it does not work.
I can clear screen and I can fill it with any color, but I can't draw anything on it.
And I know, this question was asked lots of times, but I could not found any answer on Swift.
More over, there is no any info about using OpenGL ES with Swift, so I came here.

Here is my code:

```
import GLKit

class MyGLKit: GLKView {
    override func drawRect(rect: CGRect) {
        glClearColor(0.8, 0.8, 0.8, 1.0)
        glClear(GLbitfield(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT))

        glColor4f(0, 0, 0, 1)

        var line: [GLfloat] = [-1, 0, 1, 0]
        var len = line.count * sizeof(GLfloat)

        // Create an handle for a buffer object array
        var bufferObjectNameArray: GLuint = 0

        // Have OpenGL generate a buffer name and store it in the buffer object array
        glGenBuffers(1, &bufferObjectNameArray);

        // Bind the buffer object array to the GL_ARRAY_BUFFER target buffer
        glBindBuffer(GLbitfield(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER), bufferObjectNameArray);

        // Send the line data over to the target buffer in GPU RAM
        glBufferData(
        GLbitfield(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER),    // the target buffer
        len,                            // the number of bytes to put into the buffer
        line,                           // a pointer to the data being copied
        GLbitfield(GL_STATIC_DRAW));    // the usage pattern of the data

        glVertexPointer(2, GLbitfield(GL_FLOAT), 0, line);
        var programHandle: GLuint = glCreateProgram()
        glLinkProgram(programHandle)

        glDrawArrays(GLbitfield(GL_LINES), 0, 2);
    }
}
```

I'm not sure what this code doing, cause OpenGL ES seems insanely, after usual OpenGL. I mean, you need to write a lot of code just to draw a single line. Why does it work that way?

Comment: You'll need the `glVertexPointer()` call that you commented out. But use `0` as the last argument, since this is the offset into the buffer if a buffer is bound.

Comment: @RetoKoradi I can't use `0` as the last argument, because XCode says `Cannot invoke 'init' with an argument list of type '(IntegerLiteralConvertible, $T3, IntegerLiteralConvertible, IntegerLiteralConvertible)'`. The last argument is _Specifies a pointer to the first coordinate of the first vertex in the array_. So it must be a pointer to the first element of the array. But how to make it?

Comment: I agree with OP, OpenGL-ES with swift is `insane`.  I just want to draw a damn line from pointA to pointB. Why the hell does this need 20+ lines of gl code?  Why the isn't this a primitive?  +1 for `insane`

Answer (score 0):

I have not used Swift, but based on code in [OpenGL EXC_BAD_ACCESS when calling glDrawElements in Swift but not in Objective-C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24471254/opengl-exc-bad-access-when-calling-gldrawelements-in-swift-but-not-in-objective), your `glVertexPointer()` call should look like this:

```
let bufferOffset: CConstVoidPointer = COpaquePointer(UnsafePointer<Int>(0))
glVertexPointer(2, GLbitfield(GL_FLOAT), 0, bufferOffset);
```

It also looks like you're not really building a shader program:

```
var programHandle: GLuint = glCreateProgram()
glLinkProgram(programHandle)
```

There's a bunch of things that need to go between here if you're using plain OpenGL. You need to create shader objects, give them code written in GLSL, make calls to compile the shaders, etc. I believe GLKit has functionality to use pre-baked shaders.

As for why OpenGL is so "insane", that's beyond the scope of this site. And very subjective. IMHO, the main point to keep in mind is that OpenGL is not designed to be a convenient API for programmers. It is designed to provide a relatively thin generic abstraction for accessing graphics hardware. And the tendency for comparable APIs is actually to make the abstraction layer even thinner to reduce overhead (see e.g. DirectX 12).

There's nothing stopping anybody from implementing more convenient higher level APIs on top of OpenGL. These interfaces exist, and people use them.

Comment: I've got this `Use of undeclared type 'CConstVoidPointer'` error. When I changed type to `UnsafePointer` it worked, but still nothing is drawn.

Comment: I would invite you to edit the answer, but chances are that your edit will be rejected since it will have to go through the edit review queue. Beyond this, it looks like you're missing to build a shader program. I added a paragraph about that. Sorry if my answer is not very helpful. Not sure if I should delete it. I normally don't answer questions about topics I don't understand, which includes Swift.

Comment: I think that you're right. It's so difficult to make it work! Also It doesn't make sense, because I don't need 3D graphics. All I want - draw primitives line lines and circles. Probably, you may name a few of that "_more convenient higher level APIs on top of OpenGL_"?

Comment: @Yuri, you can use CGContext.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you need to add GLKBaseEffect

Anyway here is my working solution:
To test, create a MyGLKit.swift file

```
import Foundation
import GLKit
import OpenGLES

struct OpenGLColor {
    var r: GLubyte = 0
    var g: GLubyte = 0
    var b: GLubyte = 0
    var a: GLubyte = 0
}

class MyGLKit: GLKView {

    var lineData: [GLfloat] = []
    var colorData: [GLubyte] = []
    var linesCount:Int = 0

    func setup(){
        self.context = EAGLContext(api: .openGLES2)!
        EAGLContext.setCurrent(self.context)

        //effect
        let effect: GLKBaseEffect = GLKBaseEffect()
        let projectionMatrix: GLKMatrix4 = GLKMatrix4MakeOrtho(-1.0, 1.0, -1.0, 1.0, 1.0, -1.0)
        effect.transform.projectionMatrix = projectionMatrix
        effect.prepareToDraw()


        //OPTIONAL > disable slow GL extensions
        glDisable(GLenum(GL_DEPTH_TEST))
        glDisable(GLenum(GL_BLEND))
        glDisable(GLenum(GL_DITHER))
        glDisable(GLenum(GL_STENCIL_TEST))
        glDisable(GLenum(GL_TEXTURE_2D))
        //

        glTexParameteri(GLenum(GL_TEXTURE_2D), GLenum(GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER), GL_NEAREST)
        glTexParameteri(GLenum(GL_TEXTURE_2D), GLenum(GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER), GL_NEAREST)
        glEnableVertexAttribArray(GLuint(GLKVertexAttrib.position.rawValue))
        glEnableVertexAttribArray(GLuint(GLKVertexAttrib.color.rawValue))

    }

    func drawLine(x:GLfloat, y:GLfloat, x2:GLfloat, y2:GLfloat, color: OpenGLColor){

        //suppport for retina
        var x = x
        var y = y
        var x2 = x2
        var y2 = y2
        x *= 2
        x2 *= 2
        y *= 2
        y2 *= 2

        //calculate position for opengl
        let w: GLfloat = GLfloat(self.bounds.size.width)
        let h: GLfloat = GLfloat(self.bounds.size.height)

        //coordinates x/y
        lineData.append(((1.0/w)*x)-1)
        lineData.append(1-((1.0/h)*y))
        lineData.append(0)
        lineData.append(((1.0/w)*x2)-1)
        lineData.append(1-((1.0/h)*y2))
        lineData.append(0)

        //color
        colorData.append(color.r)
        colorData.append(color.g)
        colorData.append(color.b)
        colorData.append(color.a)
        colorData.append(color.r)
        colorData.append(color.g)
        colorData.append(color.b)
        colorData.append(color.a)

        linesCount += 1

    }

    override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {

        glLineWidth(1.0)
        glClearColor(0.8, 0.8, 0.8, 1.0)
        glClear(GLbitfield(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT))

        //draw layer
        if (lineData.count > 0){
            glVertexAttribPointer(GLuint(GLKVertexAttrib.position.rawValue), 3, GLenum(GL_FLOAT), GLboolean(GL_FALSE), 0, lineData)
            glVertexAttribPointer(GLuint(GLKVertexAttrib.color.rawValue), 4, GLenum(GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE), GLboolean(GL_TRUE), 0, colorData)
            glDrawArrays(GLenum(GL_LINES), 0, GLsizei(linesCount*2))
        }
    }

}
```

Then use it for example in your UIViewController:

```
let g = MyGLKit()
        g.setup()
        g.frame = self.view.bounds
        self.view.addSubview(g)
        var color = OpenGLColor()
        color.r = 20
        color.b = 30
        color.g = 40
        color.a = 255
        g.drawLine(x: 10, y: 10, x2: GLfloat(g.frame.size.width), y2: 10, color: color)
        g.drawLine(x: 10, y: 50, x2: GLfloat(g.frame.size.width), y2: 50, color: color)
        g.setNeedsDisplay()
```